# Drupal 7 views service not return all the node fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-services

I am using drupal 7 and views service to return service for node but it is not working 100%

here is a screenshot for my view
[image]

and here is the result in the view

[image]

but the expiry date not appear in the service link
[image]

What is the problem with this view?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the label for the Expiry date into "Expiry_date" without space.